# Maintaining "user logged in state" in react manually typing in links

Tags: reactjs

I am working on this react app, I am already using JWT token, I am using react router to determine where I go to based on link. First of all, here's an interesting thing I observed: I have a redux state called auth which stores username, id, etc. If I travel to another component by calling **this.props.history.push(...)** which is a react router thing, the component I travelled to will retain the correct redux state. However, if I use the basic HTML **href**, the user state will not be maintained. Does anyone know why is that?

**Anyways, my actual concern is if a user decides to straight up type in the link to his or her profile directly, the state will not be maintained**, any insights on solving this problem?

Also, I understand that I should keep my question as specific as possible, but on the side note, is anyone familiar with triggering auto login with JWT in react when user visits the website? It appears that it has something to do with checking the secret Key JWT stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why navigation works and `href` doesn't is exactly the same reason why people directly accessing the site does not get values from the state.

Since the values in the state are stored in `the memory` and not `persisted`, it is not dynamically loaded when a user re-visits the site. You could store the state in the localStorage (or indexedDB) and reload it to redux store if it already exists in the App.js. You could use libraries like `redux-persist` to do so.

Comment: Hey @Dhananjai! Thanks for your response, it is informative. By the way, is localStorage the same as cookies? And between localStorage and indexedDB, which one would you prefer? :)

Comment: Sry, shouldn't have asked that without doing some research first. Just learned that they are two different things, both capable of storing JWT. It seems that the stackoverflow answers I read on this are leaning towards using localStorage. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> Difference between this.props.history.push(...) and href

history.push pushes a new entry onto the history stack - aka redirecting the user to another route.
You can read more about it here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

href: This will plainly redirect the user to the new page without maintaining or passing the history stack to the new page.

> if a user decides to straight up type in the link to his or her profile directly, the state will not be maintained

This is where the protected routes of the react-router comes into the play. 
You will check if the user is logged in or not before rendering the protected route.
In this way, even if the user types in the protected user and the user is not logged in, the user will be redirected to the login page.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow